# Is prioritization of tasks in Threadpool possible in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, threadpool

Is prioritization of tasks in Threadpool possible in .NET?

I have a list of.. A LOT.. of `Actions`. I want to run them in threadpool.. but.
What I'm trying to do, is to setup the threadpool, so it works this way:

1. Give the first action/task the highest priority - focus only on first task.
2. Rest of tasks will get lowest priority.
3. When first task is finished, set the highest priority to the second task.
4. When second is finished, set the highest priority to the third task, etc etc.

It's like when you want to download the entire season of TV Show from torrents (which I don't recommend) and start watching as soon as possible.

Can I set up a threadpool like this? Or is there a better solution than threadpool?

I was trying to do many solutions, but everything was "too manual". Like, running separate `Task.Factory.StartNew` thread along side `ThreadPool`. Or running threads only through `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

EDIT: 
Ok, looking at the first comment here, maybe I wasn't clear enough. My single task/action is multithreaded. It needs 3-4 threads. Running 100,000 of such tasks in a sync queue doesn't make sense, because I will use just 3-4 threads at the time. What I'm trying is:
(ok, let's say we have a queue) 1st task in the queue gets everything it wants (up to 4 threads, right?)... I still have 4 free threads (or more, depending on machine). I don't want to waste them so I want to run other tasks there... is it crazy?

**EDIT2:**
Right now I use just a threadpool. It's really bad. I have 8 core-cpu. I started 40 tasks just for a test. It computes almost 40 at once... Meaning, for the first result I need to wait 10min (it's 30s/task running sync)

Comment: So you want to get a bunch of threads and make them run in a queue sync and not async (which is the reason to use threads)?

Comment: For example: if you have 8 threads. I want 1st taskto be run on 4 threads, and 100,000 remaining tasks on remaining 4 threads. When 1st is finished, 2nd gets best priority.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [HPC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514029(v=ws.11).aspx) only for local threads.  I know of no way to adjust priority once the thread kicks off.  Infact with HPC or Hadoop, you can't change the number of CPU's once it originally grabs them.  What if you suspended all of the threads except the first 4 and as one completes, you could let another resume

Comment: Just so I understand: do all of your tasks require 3 - 4 threads? if so, you could have a queue and kick them off two at a time. Parallel.ForEach might be an option here too but that doesn't give a guarantee as to exactly how many threads it'll use.

Comment: This sounds like you want a custom task scheduler.  There is [this example for limiting the number of threads used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_7).  Perhaps you can modify to suit your additional constraints.

Comment: @EJoshuaS So, the number of threads the task needs and the number of threads available are variables. I you have 4 threads on your machine and task needs 8, then it will be running sync. The most important is the first/next task, rest of them should be run only if there are resources (threads) not in use.

Comment: Quick side note: 4 cores doesn't mean that you can only have 4 threads (looking in Task Manager I'm running 2400 actually), so if you schedule more threads than there are CPUs the worst that'll happen is one core will be running multiple threads.That does *not* mean that the entire thing is 100% synchronous;for example, if you have 5 threads and 4 cores, 3 of the cores could be running one of the threads and 1 core could be running 2.You also don't know in advance how many cores the OS will actually use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942632/do-threads-by-default-run-on-more-than-one-core

Answer (score 1):

Thread pool is especially designed for recycling of threads, therefore altering the priority will interfere with this philosophy.

However, while working with tasks you can do so by creating a an explicit thread in a custom made `TaskScheduler`

Windows supports seven relative thread priorities: Idle, Lowest, Below Normal, Normal, Above Normal, Highest, and Time-Critical.

High level approach -

1. Create a custom `TaskScheduler` by extenting `TaskScheduler`.
2. The key point here is that `TaskScheduler` will use a separate thread (with the priority you desire) to process the en-queued tasks
3. `Task.Factory.StartNew` will use this custom `TaskScheduler` to execute the task.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating 4 remaining threads to 100,000 tasks seems inefficient, especially since you'll want to rush the 2nd task once the 1st task is done. Why don't you do something else - allocate 4 threads for the first task, 4 threads for the second task and so on until you run out of CPUs. Once one of the tasks is done, allocate threads for the next in queue.